# Trigger Apache Velocity #set Parameter using a button (HTML / JS)

Tags: javascript, html, velocity, polarion, velocity-template-language

Is it possible to trigger a **Velocity Template Language** #set value to parameter via a button?

I am trying to combine HTML, JS and Velocity doing the following:

```
#set($ld=$pageParameters.Work_Item_Link_Direction.values)

<button id="demo2">up</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('demo2').onclick = function() {
   #set( $ld = "up" )
   alert("button2 was clicked");
};
</script>
```

The part, however, which doesn't work in this code is:

```
#set ( $ld = "up")
```

as it isn't pure JavaScript.

Any hints or ideas how I can combine anyway this "#set value to parameter" as function `onclick` to the button? I am working inside the application Polarion ALM.

Or is there any other approach how I can set a value to a (page) parameter using velocity and using a Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little misconception, here:

- the Velocity Template Language code is evaluated at the time the page is sent by the HTTP server, on the server itself.
- the Javascript code is evaluated once the page is loaded, in the browser.

So what you ask for doesn't really make sense.

What you *can* do, however, is trigger an ajax call from inside your javascript handler, which can set some value inside the session, return some value to the success ajax handler, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the hints. Can you provide me any example please?

Comment: You'll find many examples and tutorials online of ajax calls, [using jquery](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-ajax-with-jquery--cms-25126) or [without jquery](https://www.webucator.com/tutorial/learn-ajax/ajax-applications.cfm).